# GAE and multi-client app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am wondering about GAE possibilities and multi-client support; so the question is can GAE support multi-client app; for example, I have war files as

- 1) war A (supports datastore)
- 2) war B (send message form - saves data with A)
- 3) war C (gets messages list ui - gets saved data)

may GAE make such kind of project possible; if yes how to set controller servlet?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-client"? That could mean a number of things, and you're not clear about what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I mean to have ability not to write just ONE web app to create a project which require many services; As an example, in my question I described a project with two client apps and one datastore app. Two clients use the their common datastore. Of course, the question of security is very important that's why I mention authentification rules how to

Comment: What do you mean by "client app", in this case? Does it run on the user's computer? If it runs on the server, why not just write a single app in the first place?

Comment: I mean a common GWT RPC app so it runs both on client and server machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Remote API to access another app's datastore. See here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html#Configuring_Remote_API_on_an_App_Engine_Client

Answer (score 1):

Technically each App runs in a sandboxed environment so one app (WAR File) would not be able to access other's datastore directly. You might have to expose services/integration points to get that done. If your needs is a multi client application (multitenancy), you could use Namespace API in GAE

Comment: Could you provide more detailed information about the Namespace API; can it allow user and admin apps being develop? Some authentification rules?

Comment: Namespace would be good only if you want to compartmentalize your data, which does not seem to be need of your application. You can check documenatation at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/

Comment: can it support *.ear then?